# oracle to postgres, DATE field is in error while inserting

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, postgresql-9.4

```
INSERT INTO ASSOCIATE_MERCHANT_INFO(start_date,end_date)  
VALUES ('0002-05-05 00:00:00.0',NULL)
```

Results in:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: column "start_date" is of type timestamp without time zone but
    expression is of type character varying
[junit]   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I can see here `'0002-05-05 00:00:00.0'` is taken as char by postgres query.

I tried to typecase the select query but failed to get the success.

While extracting the data, I have tried below to typecast this date (start_date) field as below:

1. `select cast(start_date as timestamp) as start_date`
2. `select TO_TIMESTAMP(start_date) as start_date`
3. `select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(end_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS') as start_date`

Any hints?

Comment: Why  do you think that casting the column of the query does influence the insert statement? Do you understand the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to cast it to `TIMESTAMP` while inserting?

```
INSERT INTO associate_merchant_info
            (start_date,
             end_date)
VALUES  ('0002-05-05 00:00:00.0' :: TIMESTAMP,
             NULL);
```

Comment: Kaushik, Thanks for your reply. I am running select query, and then insert using an external tool. I can't modify the insert query. I tried to get the similar output by concatenating timestamp in select query itself but it output like '0002-05-05 00:00:00.0 :: TIMESTAMP' not '0002-05-05 00:00:00.0' :: TIMESTAMP

Comment: @Jay : please show the select query you tried to get  that output

Comment: @Jay please incorporate the information of this comment into your post. No one can guess that you cannot modify the insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO ASSOCIATE_MERCHANT_INFO(start_date,end_date) 
VALUES (to_timestamp('0002-05-05 00:00:00.0', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS'),NULL);
```